# Need a small help in SVG animation

Tags: html, xml, animation, svg, path

I have been trying hard to set the animation on circle. I have reached to this point :

```html
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 376 56.6" enable-background="new 0 0 376 56.6" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#232527" d="M345.8,53.3C345.8,53.3,345.8,53.3,345.8,53.3c-1.1,0-2.2-0.7-2.7-1.7l-21.7-44c-0.7-1.5-0.1-3.3,1.4-4
 c1.5-0.7,3.3-0.1,4,1.4l19,38.6l19.2-38.6c0.7-1.5,2.5-2.1,4-1.3c1.5,0.7,2.1,2.5,1.3,4l-21.9,44C348,52.6,347,53.3,345.8,53.3z
  M274.5,53.3c-1.7,0-3-1.3-3-3v-44c0-1.7,1.3-3,3-3s3,1.3,3,3v44C277.5,51.9,276.1,53.3,274.5,53.3z M205,53.3c-1.7,0-3-1.3-3-3v-41
 h-19c-1.7,0-3-1.3-3-3s1.3-3,3-3h44c1.7,0,3,1.3,3,3s-1.3,3-3,3h-19v41C208,51.9,206.7,53.3,205,53.3z M30.5,53.2
 C30.5,53.2,30.5,53.2,30.5,53.2c-1.1,0-2.2-0.7-2.7-1.7l-16-32.5v31.1c0,1.7-1.3,3-3,3s-3-1.3-3-3v-44c0-1.4,1-2.6,2.3-2.9
 C9.6,3,11,3.6,11.6,4.9l19,38.6L49.8,4.9c0.6-1.2,2-1.9,3.4-1.6c1.4,0.3,2.3,1.5,2.3,2.9v44c0,1.7-1.3,3-3,3s-3-1.3-3-3V18.9
 L33.2,51.6C32.7,52.6,31.7,53.2,30.5,53.2z"/>
<path fill="#000" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="1s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>

</svg>
```

I just want small help to move the animated loader in between M and T so that it represents that as O.

I did try play with M points and calculations but did not get success. Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance mates. Really appreciated.
Kind Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this? I've added a translate transform to the path and changed the animation to additive="sum" so it doesn't overwrite the transform.

```html
 <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 376 56.6" enable-background="new 0 0 376 56.6" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#232527" d="M345.8,53.3C345.8,53.3,345.8,53.3,345.8,53.3c-1.1,0-2.2-0.7-2.7-1.7l-21.7-44c-0.7-1.5-0.1-3.3,1.4-4
 c1.5-0.7,3.3-0.1,4,1.4l19,38.6l19.2-38.6c0.7-1.5,2.5-2.1,4-1.3c1.5,0.7,2.1,2.5,1.3,4l-21.9,44C348,52.6,347,53.3,345.8,53.3z
  M274.5,53.3c-1.7,0-3-1.3-3-3v-44c0-1.7,1.3-3,3-3s3,1.3,3,3v44C277.5,51.9,276.1,53.3,274.5,53.3z M205,53.3c-1.7,0-3-1.3-3-3v-41
 h-19c-1.7,0-3-1.3-3-3s1.3-3,3-3h44c1.7,0,3,1.3,3,3s-1.3,3-3,3h-19v41C208,51.9,206.7,53.3,205,53.3z M30.5,53.2
 C30.5,53.2,30.5,53.2,30.5,53.2c-1.1,0-2.2-0.7-2.7-1.7l-16-32.5v31.1c0,1.7-1.3,3-3,3s-3-1.3-3-3v-44c0-1.4,1-2.6,2.3-2.9
 C9.6,3,11,3.6,11.6,4.9l19,38.6L49.8,4.9c0.6-1.2,2-1.9,3.4-1.6c1.4,0.3,2.3,1.5,2.3,2.9v44c0,1.7-1.3,3-3,3s-3-1.3-3-3V18.9
 L33.2,51.6C32.7,52.6,31.7,53.2,30.5,53.2z"/>
<path fill="#000" transform="translate(100,0)" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="1s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      additive="sum"/>
    </path>

</svg>
```

Comment: Mate, Can I have this type of animation to above circle using same way we used. : http://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/ByRzOV